# Custom color of toggle buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a set of toggle buttons like this:

```css
.bs-example {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox"> Option 1
      </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox"> Option 2
      </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox"> Option 3
      </label>
</div>
```

I want to change the color of the buttons in the two toggle states. For example, when a button is active it becomes green, and it remains white other wise.

Could you help me?

Comment: So active goes to green. After that goes to white?

Comment: Make two classes in a CSS file, ActiveButton and NotActiveButton, when a button is toggled just remove and add class appropriately, and style your class to display with the correct color, green for ActiveButton and white for NotActiveButton

Comment: What have you tried so far to accomplish this? The button gets the `.active` class, you need to add the CSS for that situation.

Comment: No, I want it to remain green as long as the checkbox is checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be careful using the `!important` tag this is to help overriding the bootstrapstyle.

You can also acomplish that by declaring your stylesheet after the bootstrap css `<link>`

Hope this helps

```css
.btn:active,
.active {
  color: black !important;
  background-color: green !important;
  border-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox"> Option 1
      </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox"> Option 2
      </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox"> Option 3
      </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css for active class

```
.btn-primary.active, .btn-primary:active {
  background-color: green;
  border-color: green;
}
```

And for normal state give the label a class:

```
.someclass {
 background-color: white;
 border-color: white;
 color: black
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this - you can choose whatever color you would like.

```
.btn-group input:active{
   color:#73b2b2; 
   background-color:#73b2b2;
}
```